# ways of automatic capitalizing format in emails (webpage/outlook version)

Tags: outlook.com, email

Is there a way to automatically capitalize the 1st letters, 'I', special terms etc in emails? For lazy people not wanting to press 'shift' all the time.

Comment: Welcome. What web application are you using? Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. Ref. [help/on-topic], [ask]

Comment: I'm using webpage or outlook version of email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy-and-paste/write you email on these websites [convertcase.net](https://convertcase.net/) or [professionalediting.org](https://www.professionalediting.org/title-capitalization-tool/) and click "sentence case"

You don't have to install any extensions and it's accessible anywhere as long as you are online. It's a pretty lazy way to meet your purpose.